# Repository Pattern Dilemma: Query Duplication vs. Database Round Trips

Tags: sql, design-patterns, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I have a model consisting of two entity types:

- `Company`
- `Person`

Moreover, `Person` has a reference to `Company` via `Person.employer`, which denotes the company a person is employed at.

Now when making a call to `PersonRepository.findOne(id)`, I also need the `Person.employer` property to include the `Company` entity inline – and this is where I am facing the dilemma of having two implementational options that are both suboptimal:

**Option A)** Extra DB Calls

1. Inject the `CompanyRepository` into the `PersonRepository` to fetch the company via `CompanyRepository.findOne(id)`.
2. Fetch the `Person` with the `PersonRepository.findOne(id)`
3. Assign the company to the `Person.employer` property in memory
4. Return the result

This way, I would keep the logic to query the company encapsulated inside the `CompanyRepository` and achieve a clean separation of concerns.

The downside of this is that I make an additional round trip to the database when using the injected `CompanyRepository` to hydrate `Person.employer`.

**Option B)** Query Duplication

1. Within the `PersonRepository` use a query which selects the `Person` and also subselects the company.

On the upside, this fetches both the `Company` and the `Person` from the db in one go.

On the downside, this duplicates the query logic to fetch a `Company` that already exists in the `CompanyRepository`. Ideally, I only want the `CompanyRepository` to take care of the company selection logic in order to avoid having to maintain the same query logic in two repositories.

---

What is the preferred way to handle this situation in ASP.NET Core and EF Core? The goal is to avoide redundancy and achieving separation of concerns while minimizing the number of db calls.

Comment: you're in a field with no good outcomes and all comes from the error of referencing full `Company` on `Person`. You should only have `Person.CompanyId` (int or string). In DDD, that's why they say one aggregate root (`Person`) should have soft relation (id only) to another aggregate root (`Company`). Another reason is that if you have a full reference, that means that you could change `Company` from `Person` (by doing `Person.Company.DoSomething()` which is also anti-pattern.

Comment: @deezg thanks for your comment. I wrote "fully resolved" but what I meant is actually a company containing a minimal set of attributes such as a logo, a title and a short description, an "employee count" etc. This is needed so I am also able to display some basic company information along with the user, without making another request to the server for the company. If I just sent down the reference (`companyId`) to the client, I would have to make another request instantly.

Comment: i know, but that's a part of separate topic: splitting your read and write side of the app. For write (ddd protecting invariants) you need only `Person.CompanyId`, you use `PersonRepository` to get it from DB and you don't need to resolve anything. Completely separated, on read side where you need combined details from `Person` and `Company` you create completely new class (for example `PersonCompanyDetailsDTO`), have dedicated `ViewReaders` instead of repository and have dedicated queries there mapped to your DTO.

Comment: So you are advocating to create a service above the two repositories that does the wiring of properties (plus maybe also introducing a new DTO)? With regard to my problem, this would still result in more than one request to the db (one to retrieve the person, one for the company), which has the same drawbacks as "option two" I described above. Also creating a new service and DTO for every permutation of my Entities is not desired, I rather have the `Person` object correctly instantiated in my `PersonRepository`. But I appreciate your input on this, thanks.

Comment: not really, but never mind

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve a company by ID you need to read `Person`'s data, and fetch company ID from it. Hence if you would like to keep company-querying logic in a single place, you would end up with two round-trips - one to get company ID (along with whatever other attributes a `Person` has) and one more to get the company itself.

You could reuse the code that makes a company from `DbDataReader`, but the person+company query would presumably require joining to "forward" person's `companyId` to the `Company` query, so the text of these queries would have to be different.

You could have it both ways (one roundtrip, no repeated queries) if you move querying logic into stored procedures. This way your `person_sp` would execute `company_sp`, and return you all the relevant data. If necessary, your C# code would be able to harvest multi-part result set using `reader.NextResult()`. Now the "hand-off" of the company ID would happen on RDBMS side, eliminating the second round-trip. However, this approach would require maintaining stored procedures on RDBMS side, effectively shipping some repository logic out of your C# code base.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did not think of "stored procedures", thanks for this hint, but as you already mentioned, it has the drawback of outsourcing this logic to the RDBMS, which I really want to avoid.